# "DataTable is not a function" error inside document function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Normally, I used to initialize datatables by providing the following codes inside

```
$(function () { 
    $('#keywords-table').DataTable({ 
    "ajax": ({ 
        url: "{{ route('getKeywordsByProductId') }}", 
        method: "get",                                                  
    }), 
    "columns": [
        { "data": "action" },
        { "data": "name" },
    ]
});
```

And try to reload it by `$('#keywords-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();` (from some function inside `$(function() {});` and it worked totally fine.

But when I tried to reload it from the function below, I got following error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)DataTable is not a function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    $('#keywords-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

I tried to put

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
  $('#keywords-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

inside `$(function() {});` but the error still exists.

Let me know how to fix that issue.

Comment: having any console error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at Object.success (1:1303)
    at fire (app.js:9564)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.js:9694)
    at done (app.js:15806)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.js:16058)
    at Object.send (app.js:16110)
    at Function.ajax (app.js:15707)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (1:1282)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (app.js:11510)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (app.js:11317)

Comment: Either not loading the plugin file, trying to access it before it is loaded, or loading jQuery.js more than once in page

Comment: Have you linked the jquery dataTable CDN ?? It seems your plugin is not loaded or you forgot it

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, the problem happened only within $(document) functions and it worked totally fine out of it. And I've checked jquery and other files and they're in proper locations(before I call datatable functions for sure). For some reasons, I still need to call it within $(document) and it's a problem.

Comment: @CodeBreaker Thanks for your suggestion. Do you mean "//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ? I've included before my codes and it worked totally fine if the code is not inside $(document) function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a variable that holds value created by DataTable(). Try to change your code to

```
var myTable= $('#keywords-table').DataTable({ 
    "ajax": ({ 
        url: "{{ route('getKeywordsByProductId') }}", 
        method: "get",                                                  
    }), 
    "columns": [
        { "data": "action" },
        { "data": "name" },

    ]
});
```

and then

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    myTable.ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, I tried to fix the error in that way too. I put the table in eleTable variable but still got "Uncaught TypeError: eleTable.DataTable is not a function" error

Comment: At what line you are getting problem? Is it on initialization $('#keywords-table').DataTable({ ...?

Comment: When I tried to call  myTable.ajax.reload();. It's okay to initialize. Anyway, I've already fixed this issue by migrating all codes inside $(function() {}) and used only $(document).ready(function() { });